# github automated git clone azure-devops

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

Trying to download a second github (private) repo into a build pipeline for azure-devops. But having issues. The MS "github download release" task seems to have a bug related to downloading tags (It completes successfully but downloads 0 files etc). Been trying to do it via bash, via ssh, pat and cant find a way to download a task without need to manual put in either passwords or some sort of intervention is needed.

Does anyone have steps / guide on how to download from a private github with specific tag that  involves 0 user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pipeline is Classic UI pipeline. You can add a script task to download from your private github by running the git commands. See below steps:

**Classic Pipeline**

1, Create variables `username` and `password`(change the variable type to secret for password) in **Variables** tab.

**if your password or username contain @ replace it with %40**

[image]

2, Add a powershell task to run below inline git clone commands:

```
git config --global advice.detachedHead  false

git clone -b mytag --depth 1 https://$(username):$(password)@github.com/mygitaccount/myrepo.git -q
```

Then your private github repo will be downloaded to the folder `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/myrepo`.

**Yaml Pipeline**

If you are using Yaml pipeline. Besides of above workaround of running git commands in script tasks, you can also use [repository resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource) and [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) step.

First, you need to create a [github service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-github)(eg. `MyPrivateRepoConnection` in below example) to connect to your private github repo with your azure organization.

Then define repository resources and checkout step in your yaml pipeline. See below example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: privaterepo
    type: github
    name: myorg/myrepo
    ref: refs/tags/mytag
    endpoint: MyPrivateRepoConnection

steps:
- checkout: self #checkout the self source code of this pipeline
- checkout: privaterepo #checkout private repo
```

Comment: Thanks! yaml one works for me! didnt know that existed.. :)